# Find Missing levels and fill it

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays and  need to fill the missing values with NA by comparing the levels present in other array. I used the arr.find to search but not sure how to proceed further.

**Input:**

```
const levels = [1,2,3,4]    
const arr = [{"LEVEL":1,"NAME1":"JACK"},{"LEVEL":3,"NAME1":"TOM"}]
```

**Output:**

```
out = [{"LEVEL":1,"NAME1":"JACK"},{"LEVEL":2,"NAME1":"NA"},{"LEVEL":3,"NAME1":"TOM"},{"LEVEL":4,"NAME1":"NA"}]
```

**Code:**

```
let presentLevels = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= levels.length; i++) {
  let check = arr.find(p => p['LEVEL'] === levels[i])
  if (check) {
    presentLevels.push(i)
  }
}
console.log(presentLevels)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map()` the `levels` array. Find the object with `LEVEL` equal to the current element. If you find an object then just return that otherwise return a new object with `LEVEL` and `NAME1` props

```js
const levels = [1,2,3,4]    
const arr = [{"LEVEL":1,"NAME1":"JACK"},{"LEVEL":3,"NAME1":"TOM"}]
   
const res = levels.map(x => (arr.find(a => a.LEVEL === x) || {level: x, NAME1: "NA"}));

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a loop with `levels` to get the items which `arr` doesn't have, then adding that items to `arr`

```js
const levels = [1,2,3,4]    
const arr = [{"LEVEL":1,"NAME1":"JACK"},{"LEVEL":3,"NAME1":"TOM"}]

var items = levels.filter(level => !arr.find(item => item.LEVEL === level));

items.forEach(level => arr.push({LEVEL: level, NAME1: "NA"}));

console.log(arr.sort((a, b) => a.LEVEL - b.LEVEL));
```

Comment: The result is not sorted. The output of OP contains objects sorted according to `LEVEL`

Answer (score 1):

Using `Array.find()` inside a loop might cause a performance issue if the `arr` is large enough. I would create a Map of existing levels by `LEVEL`, and then use the Map to get the existing levels.

Since you want the `presentLevels` array to be ordered by the number of the level, you'll need to iterate the `levels` array, and return a new array. You can do this easily with `Array.map()`. On each iteration take the current level from the `existing` Map, and if not found in `existing` return a new object with NA.

```js
const levels = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const arr = [{"LEVEL":1,"NAME1":"JACK"},{"LEVEL":3,"NAME1":"TOM"}]

const existingMap = new Map(arr.map(o => [o.LEVEL, o]))

const presentLevels = levels.map(LEVEL =>
  existingMap.get(LEVEL) || { LEVEL, NAME1: 'NA' }
);

console.log(presentLevels)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could first map the `levels` to the object array with all `NA`, and then iterate `arr` to replace those where necessary:

```js
const levels = [1,2,3,4];    
const arr = [{"LEVEL":1,"NAME1":"JACK"},{"LEVEL":3,"NAME1":"TOM"}];
  
const result = levels.map(LEVEL => ({LEVEL, NAME1: "NA"}) );
for (let o of arr) result[o.LEVEL-1] = o;

console.log(result);
```

Although this executes two loops, they are not nested, and so this task is performed with linear time complexity (contrary to solutions that have a `find` call inside the loop).

Answer (score 1):

maybe like this:

```js
   const levels = [1,2,3,4];
   const arr = [{"LEVEL":1,"NAME1":"JACK"},{"LEVEL":3,"NAME1":"TOM"}];

   for(var key_l in levels){
       var found_levels = false;
       for(var key_ar in arr){
           if(arr[key_ar].LEVEL == levels[key_l]){
               found_levels = true;
           }
       }
       if(!found_levels){
          arr.push({"LEVEL":levels[key_l],"NAME1":"NA"});
       }
   }
   
   /* for result sorting, if need... */
   arr.sort(function(a, b){
     return a.LEVEL > b.LEVEL;
   });
   
   console.log(arr);
```